# Python pass a dictionary as an argument

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, arguments

I'm trying to pass a dictionary `opt_chain` as an argument

```
opt_chain = {
  'symbol': 'AAPL',
  'contractType': 'CALL',
  'optionType': 'S',
  'fromDate': '2021-07-18',
  'afterDate': '2021-07-19',
  'strikeCount': 4,
  'includeQuotes': True,
  'range': 'ITM',
  'strategy': 'ANALYTICAL',
  'volatility': 29.0
}
```

to the function api `get_options_chain`

But I get the following error

```
    option_chains = td_client.get_options_chain(args_dictionary = opt_chain)
TypeError: get_options_chain() got an unexpected keyword argument 'args_dictionary'
```

Here is the code that I run (excerpt):

```html
opt_chain = {
  'symbol': 'AAPL',
  'contractType': 'CALL',
  'optionType': 'S',
  'fromDate': '2021-07-18',
  'afterDate': '2021-07-19',
  'strikeCount': 4,
  'includeQuotes': True,
  'range': 'ITM',
  'strategy': 'ANALYTICAL',
  'volatility': 29.0
}

option_chains = td_client.get_options_chain(args_dictionary = opt_chain)
pprint.pprint(option_chains)
```

This is Python v3.6.9

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code is perfect here, but the way you're calling the `get_options_chain` function of the TDClient library is incorrect.

Let's walk through this...
The error you're receiving here is
`TypeError: get_options_chain() got an unexpected keyword argument 'args_dictionary'`. This indicates that the function is not expecting a parameter called `args_dictionary` which you are setting in your parameters here `(args_dictionary = opt_chain)`.

After looking at the library, I believe the fix is just passing in the dictionary without defining it as an argument, like so:

```py
option_chains = td_client.get_options_chain(opt_chain)
```

If you look at the [source code for the function](https://github.com/areed1192/td-ameritrade-python-api/blob/a3aabf2228eb615f579a5208fa2249f506f926a5/td/client.py#L910), it does not require you to strictly define the argument name, and only takes in one argument anyways.

Answer (score 0):

In your code,
option_chains = td_client.get_options_chain(args_dictionary = opt_chain)
here args_dictionary was not expected in the API call, it should be 'option_chain'

option_chains = td_client.get_options_chain(option_chain=opt_chain)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, `td_client.get_options_chain` method is not taking an argument called `args_dictionary`. It is expecting an argument called `option_chain`. You can either pass `opt_chain` as keyword argument like `td_client.get_options_chain(option_chain = opt_chain)` or you can directly pass `opt_chain` like `td_client.get_options_chain(opt_chain)` since it is the first argument `td_client.get_options_chain` is expecting.

```
    option_chains = td_client.get_options_chain(option_chain = opt_chain)
```

OR

```
    option_chains = td_client.get_options_chain(opt_chain)
```